# [MS Access VBA]How to create a table with an autonumbered primary key with text prefix

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Currently, I have a VBA code that creates table with autonumbered primary key(Field name: Code). It looks like this.

```
SQL1 = "CREATE TABLE [" + Replace(Me.RecordNo.Value, ".", "p") + "_Inspect] (Code COUNTER(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Description TEXT, Last_inspection DATE, Recent_inspection DATE, Next_inspection DATE, Inspection_type TEXT, inspection_equipment TEXT, Inspection_result TEXT)"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL1
```

But for 'Code', I want to change the format of this primary key. For now, this is simply a primary key with incremental number(1, 2, 3, 4, 5...) but I want to add text prefix to it, like (Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4....). How can I do that?

Thankyou in advance, sincerely.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

AutoNumbers are just numbers. Including text with them would have a significant impact on ordering (in text ordering, Code9 is greater than Code10 since 9 is greater than 1), thus leading to massive fragmentation.

Instead, you can change the formatting of the autonumber to display "Code" in front of the number (while not storing it), or use a second, calculated field that stores "Code" and then the autonumber.

Do note that dynamically creating tables is a strong indicator of a non-normalized database. Consider adjusting your database to not need dynamically created tables.

To change the format, you can use the following code:

```
Dim td As DAO.TableDef
Set td = CurrentDb.TableDefs(MyTableName)
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Set fld = td.Fields!MyFieldName
Dim prp As DAO.Property
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, """Code""#")
fld.Properties.Append prp
```

This assumes the format property hasn't been initialized yet. Else, you can simpy use the following code:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs(MyTableName).Fields!MyField.Properties!Format = """Code""#"
```